# Coin fall / Bernoulli formula probability

Tags: math, probability, probability-theory

I'm confused by my result. I'm trying to solve the exercise:

"What is the probability that a coin with a probability of 1/3 of the decision to fall (tail) will fall exactly 10 times with a tail with 30 attempts?"

I got a strange result: `1.4592670745133494e-07` (Bernoulli formula)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

```
def fac(n):
    return math.factorial(n)

a = fac(30)
b = fac(10)
c = fac(20)

(a / (b * c)) * (1/3)** 30

=> 1.4592670745133468e-07
```

Answer (score 2):

You applied the formula incorrectly: there should be tails (probability 1/3) 10 times, and heads (probability 1-1/3=2/3) 30-10=20 times.

So,

```
(1/3)** 30
```

should be

```
(1/3)** 10 * (2/3)** 20
```

giving 0.153 as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

When doing probability calculations in Python, it is often useful to simulate the experiment so as to compare it with your attempted exact calculation. A naive version would be:

```
import random

def simulate(n,k,prob = 0.5,trials = 10000):
    """estimates the probability of seeing exactly k heads in n rolls"""
    successes = 0
    for i in range(trials):
        trial = ''.join('H' if random.random() < prob else 'T' for _ in range(n))
        if trial.count('H') == k: successes += 1
    return successes/trials
```

For example, my first run of `simulate(30,10,1/3)` evaluated to `0.1525`, which meshes with the answer of Julius Vainora.